# Resources for Learning Octave

Tags: online-resources

I belive Octave is a popular free/OSS alternative to MatLab? So where can I find some resource for learning how to use it? Perferrably videos but any will do.

Comment: More than an alternative, Octave is basically a free Matlab clone. The syntax and the basic built-in functions are almost the same, and so the tutorials and basic docs for Matlab apply also to Octave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can freely download and install Octave on your computer. The download contains also a good documentation. Then you can search for more documentation for Octave and Matlab on the Internet.
There is specially a lot of documentation for Matlab, and the good thing is that you can use it to a great extent also for Octave. And I recommend not only to read but also to try it out in your Octave.